# React - Call class function from another component - 'Not a function'

Tags: reactjs

I have an 'Auth' class with a 'signIn()' function that I'm trying to call from a 'Login' component, that returns the error 'not a function' when it attempts to use the callback in 'Login'.

I've tried referring to the Auth class/service via use of a prop (like `this.props.auth.signIn()`), and directly as via a call to the class in the Login component (like `this.auth`), but both result in the same error.

I'm trying to follow the method used in the official documentation for Auth0's react samples at https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-samples/blob/embedded-login/02-Custom-Login-Form/src/Login/Login.js.

**Auth.js:**

```
import auth0 from 'auth0-js';
import { auth_config } from './auth0-config';
import createHistory from 'history';

export default class Auth {

  auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
      ...
  })

  constructor() {
        this.signIn = this.signIn.bind(this);
  }

  signIn(username, password) {
        this.auth0.login(
              {
                    realm: auth_config.dbConnectionName,
                    username,
                    password
              },
              (err, authResult) => {
                    if (err) {
                          console.error('Authentication error at \'services/auth/Auth.js\' - signIn() method:', err);
                          alert(`Error: ${err.description}. Check the console for further details.`);
                    }
              }
        )
  }
```

**Login.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Auth from 'services/auth/Auth.js';

import { Dimmer, Modal, Header, Form, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';

export default class LoginComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        showModal: true,
        username: null,
        password: null,
        authorised: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Login.props:', this.props);
  }

  hide = () => {
    console.log('LoginComponent.hide()');
    this.setState({
        showModal: false
    })
  }

  getLoginCredentials() {
    return {
        email: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.email).value,
        password: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.password).value
    }
  }

  signIn() {
    //   console.log('LoginComponent.signIn(\'' + this.state.username + '\', \'' + this.state.password + '\')');

    const user = this.getLoginCredentials();
    this.props.auth.signIn(user.email, user.password);
  }
```

Comment: Where are you passing the `Auth` to the props ? Have your tried directly using `Auth.signIn(user.email, user.password);`

Comment: I have tried that, but it returns a similar error: '__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_services_auth_Auth_js__.a.signIn is not a function'

Comment: Try then `(new Auth).signIn(user.email, user.password);`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create the object of the class and then using that object you can call the function inside your Login.js,

```
signIn() {

    const user = this.getLoginCredentials();
    let signinObj = new Auth();
    signinObj.signIn(user.email, user.password);
  }
```

Edit: In the [github page,](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-samples/blob/embedded-login/02-Custom-Login-Form/src/routes.js) in router.js file you can see the statment,

```
  <Route path="/login" render={(props) => <Login auth={auth} {...props} />} />
```

auth is the object of this class which is passed to Login class as props.

Comment: This is not how it's instructed in the official documentation for auth0 at https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-samples/blob/embedded-login/02-Custom-Login-Form/src/Login/Login.js

Comment: That is because, here these are two seperare independent classes where as in the github page the login component is a child component of auth component